# Blueimp upload php script change preg_replace_callback regex

Tags: php, regex, blueimp

I want to change this regex in upcount_name function :

```
protected function upcount_name_callback($matches) {
    $index = isset($matches[1]) ? intval($matches[1]) + 1 : 1;
    $ext = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
    return ' ('.$index.')'.$ext;
}

protected function upcount_name($name) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/(?:(?: \(([\d]+)\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/', 
    array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),$name,1);
}
```

from blueimp upload script.
This script change name in order to get unique files name like this "image (1).jpg", "image (2),jpg" and so on....(please notice the space between base name and number inside brackets)

Now i want to get back "image-1.jpg","image-2.jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you have unique files named like "image-1.jpg","image-2.jpg" etc? If so I think you could change the regex to behave the same (but matching that format), like this:

```
return preg_replace_callback('/(?:(?:-([\d]+))?(\.[^.]+))?$/'
```

But I may have completely misunderstood.

Comment: My fault...my english...my hurry.Thank you

Comment: Glad the answer helped =D

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you want simply change the return line as below

```
 protected function upcount_name_callback($matches) {
        $index = isset($matches[1]) ? intval($matches[1]) + 1 : 1;
        $ext = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
        return '-'.$index.'.$ext; // replaced this return ' ('.$index.')'.$ext;
    }

protected function upcount_name($name) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/(?:(?: \(([\d]+)\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/', 
    array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),$name,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A superguy from here, post the solution but his answer was deleted, so I post here with thank's for the superguy...

```
/(?:(?:-([\d]+))?(\.[^.]+))?$/
```

Comment: Oh, I thought I'd completely misunderstood the question =O Undeleted.